# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n! (4x - 5y)^n $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Where does the following series converge?
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n! (4x - 5y)^n $$

Any (x,y) from the line $4x=5y$ gives series that consists of zero terms, hence, converges.

I need help in determining other possible pairs or proving that this is it.

BTW, is there any name for such series?

Comment: Don't you have any kind of rules or tests to help you determine convergence?

Comment: I do, but they (ratio test, integral test and so on) applies to series of 1 variable, right? In this case, I have - 3 variables.

Comment: Have you considered the series $\sum n!a^n$? For what $a$ does that converge?

Comment: Ratio test gives $\lim \left(n+1\right)\left(4x-5y\right)$, hence there is no other cases beside the line $4x-5y$ because the limit will be $>1$.

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}$

Comment: n is not a variable, it's an index. Let $z=4x-5y$ to reduce to a single variable.

Comment: Hm, so, the area of application of these tests is much wider that I thought. Thank you, blue.

Comment: @AdamHughes, right, I meant that usually, I deal with something like $\sum n^2 + sqrt(n)/n!$ or power series like $\sum x^n/n!$. Here, having 2 variables confused me, so I thought there may be a catch in the problem.

Comment: Again, $n$ is not a variable, it's a index, but let's set that aside. You can use the same tests, it's just that you'll get an answer in terms of the variable.

Example:  

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

The root test says this converges when

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{|x^n|}<1\iff |x|<1\; .$$

Comment: @AdamHughes, got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and apply the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test).